# Will Kali Linux on VMware virtual machine recognize 2 identical WIFI adapters?

Tags: wireless-networking, virtual-machine, kali-linux, adapter

I need 2 WIFI adapters. I already have 1 : Alfa AWUS036NHA. I'm going to buy the same one, because I found it really useful and powerful. so I wonder if kali Linux will have problems by recognizing both of them.im using VMware virtual machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Won't be a problem.
Even if 2 pieces of hardware are exactly the same, they will NEVER be connected via the same path.
Different USB ID-numbers in case of USB, different slots in case of PCI and PCIe cards, different SATA ports in case of harddisks.
And that is all the information the OS needs to keep them apart.

Comment: thank you, so VMware won't have problem as well right?

Comment: VMware will recognize a wireless card as an Ethernet adapter in the virtual machine. If you want a wireless adapter in the VM you need to use USB passthrough and a USB wireless card.

Comment: @john Yes. And USB pass-though often doesn't work very well. That is a general issue with USB pass-though in virtual machines. It depends a lot of the USB device, the USB controller, the host-OS and the guest-OS. In my experience VirtualBox is better at that than other virtualization products, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: I have Kali as a VMware VM here and USB passthrough works great. The main NIC in Kali shows up as Ethernet here.

Comment: @John Count yourself lucky. Over the last 10 years I've had to use USB pass-though for Wifi adapters and regular NICS on at least 25 different computers and multiple virtualisations suites (VirtualBox, VMWare, Parallels). It was mostly hot and miss. Some computers it wouldn't work (or be unstable) no matter what I did. Just copying the VM to another computer was often enough to make it work. In other case switching hypervisor did the trick. VirtualBox worked fine 6 times out of 10 on the first try. VMWare and parallels did worse (about 3 out of 10).